# adding users by contacts ios

Tags: ios, database, security

I have an app where users create accounts by username and password. However, I also want users to be able to add friends via their mobile #. Is there a security reason as to why I would need to verify their number if my design goes as follows:

User A enters her # into app, which saves to database

User B gives app access to his contacts. User A is a contact in User B's address book. When the database is queried for all #'s in User B's contacts book, we find User A's # and User A is returned.

How could there be a security flaw if User A entered a false #?

Comment: how can that not be an issue? It is obvious that it is an issue: anybody could pretend to be someone else by using another telephone number!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That would definitely cause security issues. Of course, for an app like this, you would need some way to verify the data that you are receiving. What if one if the contacts phone numbers are wrong? Some phone numbers change all the time now and it would be difficult keeping up to date with them all.

But on a bigger note than that, I don't think this one would fly with Apple. I've never designed an app that needed to access more than one contact at a time and the user was fully aware of which contact he/she was importing to a database. But for an app to automatically upload multiple contacts from a users address book for intent to be stored on a remote database might cause security flags to be raised at Apple during the review process. So the app may never see light of day on the Apple Store.

If you really want to implement something similar, make sure users verify their phone number before use and instead of storing the users contacts on a server, just store the verified phone number. Then you can use the contacts in your phone to check mobile numbers that have been verified of other users and which ones have an account linked to them.